# Strong force equivalent of electricity?

Tags: electricity, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, quark-gluon-plasma

Could colour charges be manipulated into something analogous to the flow of electricity, and if so, would there be any situation in which circuits of this kind would be useful? For example, given a sufficiently large, stable quantity of quark-gluon plasma, in which colour charges are effectively deconfined, could the flow of these strongly interacting particles be used to perform computational tasks? Would Debye screening prevent this?